# Variable sized matrix in C

Tags: c, dynamic, size

Is there any way to create a variable sized doubly-scripted array in C (not C++, just C)? I know that to create a variable sized singly-scripted array, you just use a pointer, e.g.

```
float *array;
array = (float *) calloc(sizeof(float), n);
```

creates a singly-scripted array of floats of size n. Is there something similar that I can do for doubly-scripted arrays?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are no double-scripted arrays in C; there are only arrays of arrays. E.g. this:

```
int a[3][3];
```

Should read as "array of 3 arrays of 3 ints", not as "array of 3x3 ints". This is immediately visible from types of expressions - e.g. `a[0]` is a valid expression, and its type is `int[3]`.

For array types, array size is part of the type, and therefore must be known at compile-time. Therefore, while you can have a type "pointer to arrays" to make one dimension dynamic, the remaining ones would still have to be fixed:

```
int (*p)[3] // pointer to arrays of 3 ints each
```

There are two traditional workarounds:

1. Just use a single-dimensional dynamic array of *width* x *height* elements, and calculate 1D indices from 2D coordinates as `(y * width + x)`  yourself.
2. Use pointer to pointers:

   ```
   int** a = malloc(sizeof(int*) * height);
   for (i = 0; i < height; ++i) a[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * width);
   a[0][0] = 123;
   ...
   ```

   The problem here is that your array needs not be rectangular anymore, and you can't really enforce it. Performance-wise, it's also worse than a single contiguous block of memory.

In C99, you can also use variable-length arrays:

```
void foo(int width, int height) {
    int a[width][height];
    ...
}
```

Comment: In the second method, you don't need to do one `malloc` for every row of the array - you can still allocate it in one big block and then assign the row pointers to locations within that allocation.

Comment: for an extra example of option 1 see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063085/declaring-two-large-2d-arrays-gives-segmentation-fault/3063693#3063693

Answer (score 6):

The [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html) has a good section on this.

Answer (score 5):

You can do almost the same thing for multi dimensional arrays.

```
float **array;
array = calloc(sizeof(float*), n);
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    array[i] = calloc(sizeof(float), n);
}
```

Comment: At that point, will I just be able to call array[2][3] = 5 for example? Assuming, of course, that n > 3.

Comment: This is a little misleading - a two-dimensional array `double[][]` occupies a single segment of memory, while this stores an array of pointers to segments for each row. Sure, you can still access it with array subscripts, but it's definitely not the same thing.

Comment: @wolfPack88: Yes, but do understand how it works. `array[2]` is the third `float*` pointer stored in array, and `array[3]` takes the fourth `float` stored in the memory pointed to by `array[2]`.

Comment: @Jefromi: this has the added flexibility of allowing rows of variable lenght. For modeling the mathematical concept of a matrix it is not necessary but it can be useful.

Comment: @Jefromi That's true, but you can do something similar and have contiguous memory.

Comment: @Francesco: Yes, that's true - but the OP definitely asked about 2-d arrays. @Amuck: Yes, but you didn't explain it, while both gmatt and Pavel Minaev did - with Pavel pointing out the possible performance penalty here.

Comment: @Jefromi Yes, Pavel's answer is much more thorough and is correct.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a matrix with n rows and m columns then you can use a linear array of length `m*n` to represent this, where each index `i` represents

```
row = i  / n
col = i  % n
```

and the inverse mapping

```
i  = row * n  + col
```

Most algebra packages that use matrices like matlab actually use this representation, because it generalizes well to any dimension (you could generalize this to a 3-dimensional matrix just as well).

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not possible.  As an alternative, allocate a single array, and define an indexing function that takes your coordinate and returns an index into the array.

```
int Index(int i, int j, int numCols)
{ 
    return i * numCols + j;
}

int numRows = 100;
int numCols = 200;

float *data = malloc(sizeof(float) * numRows * numCols);

data[Index(34, 56, numCols)] = 42.0f;
```

Comment: I think you mean *(data + 34*200 + 56) = 42.0f... I just generally prefer a more literate style.

Answer (score 1):

You can use C99 variable-length arrays (works with gcc):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void foo(size_t rows, size_t cols, float array[rows][cols])
{
    printf("%f\n", array[2][3]);
}

int main(void)
{
    size_t rows = 4;
    size_t cols = 5;
    float (*array)[cols] = calloc(sizeof (float), rows * cols);
    array[2][3] = 42;
    foo(rows, cols, array);
}
```

Comment: "You can use C99 variable-length arrays." But please don't. :)

Comment: @Bobby: I don't see a reason not to if your compiler supports them - especially in a case such as this where no stack-allocations are involved...

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised no-one has pointed out the 'obvious' alternative which preserves the single contiguous allocation for the main matrix, but has the vector of pointers to give double subscripting.  (I suppose that means it isn't obvious, after all.)

```
float **array2d = malloc(sizeof(*array2d) * height);
float  *array1d = malloc(sizeof(*array1d) * height * width);

for (i = 0; i < height; ++i)
    array2d[i] = &array1d[i * width];
```

Now you can write 2-D array accesses as usual:

```
array2d[0][0] = 123.0;
```

Clearly, we also need to check the memory allocation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler way given in [geeksforgeeks.com](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamically-allocate-2d-array-c/) "Using a pointer to the first row of VLA":

```
int (*arr)[col] = calloc(row, sizeof *arr);
```

and then you can access each element simply like

```
arr[i][j]
```